# Delete keyword causing program crash

Tags: c++, memory-management, data-structures

I've created a class that uses a allocated memory for an array that is deleted via destructor. For some reason, I use the new keyword to create a pointer to a variable of this class and when I try to delete it my program crashes and gives a Heap Corruption error.

```
int main() {
    Butterflyfish *tad
        = new Butterflyfish(3, "tad");
    tad->printMemory();
    tad->remember('a');
    tad->remember('x');
    tad->remember('a');
    tad->remember('b');
    tad->remember('c');
    tad->remember('a');
    tad->remember('d');
    tad->printMemory();
    tad->forget();
    tad->printMemory();
    delete tad; //causes crash
    return 0;
}
```

The class Butterflyfish is based off of class Fish.

```
Fish::Fish(int capacity, std::string name)
{
    if (capacity < 0)
    {
        capacity = 3;
    }

    this->m_memory = new char[capacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        this->m_memory[i] = '.';
    }

    this->m_capa = capacity;
    this->m_used = 0;
    this->m_name = name;
    this->m_full = false;

}

Fish::Fish(const Fish& other)
{
    this->m_name = other.m_name;
    this->m_capa = other.m_capa;
    this->m_used = other.m_used;
    this->m_full = other.m_full;

    this->m_memory = new char[m_capa];

    for (int i = 0; i < this->m_capa; i++)
    {
        this->m_memory[i] = other.m_memory[i];
    }

}

Fish::~Fish()
{
    delete[] m_memory;
}

Fish& Fish::operator=(const Fish& other)
{
    // TODO: insert return statement here

    if ( this == &other )
    {
        return *this;
    }

    this->m_name = other.m_name;
    this->m_capa = other.m_capa;
    this->m_used = other.m_used;
    this->m_full = other.m_full;

    this->m_memory = new char[m_capa];

    for (int i = 0; i < this->m_capa; i++)
    {
        this->m_memory[i] = other.m_memory[i];
    }

    return *this;
}

void Fish::remember(char c)
{
    if (m_used != (m_capa - 1))
    {
        for (int i = m_used; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            this->m_memory[i + 1] = this->m_memory[i];
        }

        this->m_memory[0] = c;      
        this->m_used++;
    }

    else if (this->m_used == (this->m_capa - 1))
    {
        if (this->m_full)
        {
            for (int i = m_used; i > 0; i--)
            {
                this->m_memory[m_used] = this->m_memory[m_used - 1];
            }

            this->m_memory[0] = c;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = m_used; i > 0; i--)
            {
                this->m_memory[i] = this->m_memory[i - 1];
            }

            this->m_memory[0] = c;
            this->m_used = this->m_capa;

            this->m_full = true;
        }
    }

}

void Fish::forget()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_capa; i++)
    {
        this->m_memory[i] = '.';
    }

    this->m_used = 0;
    this->m_full = false;
}

void Fish::printMemory() const
{
    std::cout << "{ ";

    for (int i = 0; i < m_capa; i++)
    {
        std::cout << this->m_memory[i] << " ";
    }

    std::cout << '}' << std::endl;
}

std::string Fish::getName()
{
    return this->m_name;
}

const char* Fish::getMemory() const
{
    return m_memory;
}

int Fish::getAmount() const
{
    return this->m_used;
}

int Fish::getCapacity() const
{
    return this->m_capa;
}
```

The fish class has no errors when testing so that's only for you if you want to use it. Here's the butterfly fish class.

```
Butterflyfish::Butterflyfish(int capacity, std::string name) : Fish(capacity, name)
{
    m_extended = new OBBY[capacity];
    m_exUsed = 0;
    m_exCapa = capacity;
}

Butterflyfish::Butterflyfish(const Butterflyfish &other) : Fish(other)
{
    this->m_exCapa = other.m_exCapa;
    this->m_exUsed = other.m_exUsed;
    this->m_extended = new OBBY[this->m_exCapa];

    for (int i = 0; i < m_exUsed; i++)
    {
        this->m_extended[i].letter = other.m_extended[i].letter;
        this->m_extended[i].times = other.m_extended[i].times;
    }
}

Butterflyfish& Butterflyfish::operator=(const Butterflyfish &other)
{
    if (this == &other)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    else
    {
        Fish::operator=(other);

        this->m_exCapa = other.m_exCapa;
        this->m_exUsed = other.m_exUsed;
        this->m_extended = new OBBY[this->m_exCapa];

        for (int i = 0; i < m_exUsed; i++)
        {
            this->m_extended[i].letter = other.m_extended[i].letter;
            this->m_extended[i].times = other.m_extended[i].times;
        }

        return *this;
    }
}

Butterflyfish::~Butterflyfish()
{
    delete[] m_extended;
}

void Butterflyfish::remember(char c)
{
    Fish::remember(c);

    tolower(c);

    if (m_exUsed == m_exCapa)
    {
        OBBY* temp = new OBBY[m_exCapa];

        for (int i = 0; i < m_exCapa; i++)
        {
            temp[i].letter = m_extended[i].letter;
            temp[i].times = m_extended[i].times;
        }

        delete[] m_extended;

        m_extended = new OBBY[m_exCapa * 2];

        for (int j = 0; j < m_exUsed; j++)
        {
            m_extended[j].letter = temp[j].letter;
            m_extended[j].times = temp[j].times;
        }

        m_exCapa *= 2;

        delete[] temp;
    }

    if (m_exUsed == 0)
    {
        m_extended[0].letter = c;
        m_extended[0].times = 1;

        m_exUsed = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        bool match = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < m_exUsed; i++)
        {
            if ( m_extended[i].letter == c )
            {
                m_extended[i].times += 1;
                match = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (match == false)
        {
            m_extended[m_exUsed].letter = c;
            m_extended[m_exUsed].times += 1;
            m_exUsed += 1;
        }
    }

}

void Butterflyfish::printMemory() const
{
    Fish::printMemory();

    std::cout << "I'm Obnoxious" << std::endl;

    if (m_exUsed == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    std::cout << "I've Seen" << "\n\t";
    for (int i = 0; i < m_exUsed; i++)
    {
        if (i == (m_exUsed - 1))
        {
            std::cout << "and " << m_extended[i].letter << " " << m_extended[i].times << " times\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << m_extended[i].letter << " " << m_extended[i].times << " times\n\t";
        }
    }

}
```

The fish can remember strings of a predetermined capacity. The butterfly fish class has special skills where it can remember every letter it's seen and how many times it's seen them. It's second memory capacity can double it's capacity when it's second memory has become full.

These are the class declarations.

```
class Fish {
private:
    // TODO: declare any private member variables/functions here
    char* m_memory;
    int m_used, m_capa;
    bool m_full;
    std::string m_name;
}; //left out public stuff cuz It's posted up there

class Butterflyfish :public Fish {
private:
    struct OBBY //for obnoxious
    {
        char letter = ' ';
        int times = 0;
    };

    OBBY* m_extended;
    int m_exCapa;
    int m_exUsed;
};
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167505/discussion-on-question-by-demarcus-sales-delete-keyword-causing-program-crash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a little closer look at parts of this function

```
void Fish::remember(char c)
{
    if (m_used != (m_capa - 1))
    {
        // ...
    }

    else if (this->m_used == (this->m_capa - 1))
    {
        if (this->m_full)
        {
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            // ...
            this->m_used = this->m_capa;
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This will work fin until the moment when `m_used == m_capa - 1`.

The problem with this is that when that happens you will set `m_used = m_capa`. And in the next call `m_used != m_capa - 1` is ***true*** and you will go out of bounds of your allocated memory.

Change the initial condition from

```
if (m_used != (m_capa - 1))
```

to

```
if (m_used <= (m_capa - 1))
```

And don't do `else if (...)`, just plain `else`.

Note that this would have been very obvious is you learned how to use a debugger to step through the code line by line.

Comment: This didn't work man but thanks. I still get the Heap Corruption crash.

Comment: @DemarcusSales You probably have a similar problem somewhere else in your code. Please learn how to use a debugger and how to step through your code.

Comment: when I use the VS debugger to step trough everytime I get to the line of code it just freezes, shows a dialog box with the error. The program works perfectly up to the final delete.

Comment: actually I don't want it to equal m_capa - 1 so your fix wuldn't work bro

Comment: but your fix was correct except instead of "<=" I just wanted "<"